# Why is there -ing object after tried?

Tags: complementation, infinitive-vs-gerund

> She reveals the truth: Clare Quilty, an acquaintance of Charlotte's,
>   the writer of the school play, and the man Lolita claims to have
>   loved, checked her out of the hospital after following them throughout
>   their travels and **tried making** her star in one of his pornographic
>   films. (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lolita)

I guess after tried there needs to be to-infinitive to denote afterward plan to make her star. Why is there –ing object of tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the actual events it's impossible to be sure, but I think you're right, and what is meant is

> Clare tried **to make** her star in one of his pornographic films.

That means that he sought to compel Charlotte to appear in his film.

The idiom "try VERBing* means "to VERB as an experiment":

> I tried seasoning the chicken with anise, but it was not very good.
>   He tried traveling by train for a while and found it much less stressful.

Your sentence would be correct only if what Clare did was "try the experiment of making her star", which seems very unlikely.

Comment: I think in this case it's more likely that "*making*" means *'to force somebody to do something against their will'*  She probably didn't want to star in a porno. "Tried making" means she made an attempt to force her to star in the movie, but did not succeed in doing so."

Comment: @Jim I think that is what is **meant**; but that should be, as OP suggests, *Tried **to make** her star*. I have edited to make this clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Both "tried making" and "tried to make" would be grammatically correct. However, there is a subtle but significant difference between "tried making" and "tried to make" in this sentence.

> ... and tried making her star in...

The tense here is past continuous, which implies that he tried *over a duration of time* (i.e. more than once) to make her star in a film.

Compare this to the sentence if it was changed to the past simple tense.

> ... and tried to make her star in...

Now the implication is that he tried *just once* to make her star in a film.